# How do I add an axis label on an axis tick mark using ggplot2 in R, similar to the fivethirtyeight style?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In fivethirtyeight.com's graphs, they mostly include the y-axis label on the top tick mark of the axis. An example is seen in Ben Casselman's graph from his 2/12/2016 article 'Saudi Arabia Is Winning Its War Against The U.S. Oil Industry':[The number for the top of the y-axis scale includes the unit, like $150/barrel or 1,500 rigs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXQds.png)

I have modified a theme from the ggthemes package for ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
theme_fivethirtyeight_mod <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "sans") {
(theme_foundation(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) + 
 theme(line = element_line(colour = "black"), rect = element_rect(fill = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["ltgray"], linetype = 0, colour = NA), text = element_text(colour = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["dkgray"]), 
       axis.text = element_text(color = 'black'), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), 
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
       legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.box = "vertical", 
       panel.grid = element_line(colour = NULL), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["medgray"]), 
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = rel(1.5), face = "bold"), 
       plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "lines"), strip.background = element_rect()))
}
```

I would like to add 'IP After' to the top of the y-axis of this graph and 'IP Before' to the rightmost tick of the x-axis (which uses that theme):
[A scatterplot showing Innings Pitched before an injury versus after an injury for 81 baseball pitchers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X44tq.png)

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: The [ggthemes package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggthemes/vignettes/ggthemes.html) provides a fivethirtyeight theme.

Comment: But the ggthemes package does not allow for the fivethiryeight-style axis labels. Also, the fivethirthyeight theme sets `axis.text` to `element_blank()` and I needed some form of labeling for this graph. @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually label the ticks:

```
lab <- c(seq(40, 220, by = 20))
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(40, 240, by = 20), labels = c(lab, "240 IP before injury"))
```

That's a neat plot, do you intend to post it to the public? I would be interested in seeing more of your analysis.

**Edit:**

Using your modified theme:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

theme_fivethirtyeight_mod <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "sans") {
(theme_foundation(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) + 
 theme(line = element_line(colour = "black"), rect = element_rect(fill = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["ltgray"], linetype = 0, colour = NA), text = element_text(colour = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["dkgray"]), 
       axis.text = element_text(color = 'black'), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), 
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
       legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.box = "vertical", 
       panel.grid = element_line(colour = NULL), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight["medgray"]), 
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = rel(1.5), face = "bold"), 
       plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "lines"), strip.background = element_rect()))
}

p1 <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight)) +
geom_point(position = "jitter") +
scale_y_continuous(
  expand = c(0, 0),
  limits = c(0, 560),
  breaks = seq(0, 560, by = 185),
  labels = c(seq(0, 375, by = 185), "560 units")) +
theme_fivethirtyeight_mod()
```

[image: Plot with y-axis tick mark at the top.]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that. I am using a modified version of the ggtheme's fivethirtyeight theme, in which I add the ability for axis labels. I get a warning that I am replacing the 'y' scale, but I still end up with a numeric scale, with no text. I am still working on a paper to go along with the graph (and a couple others), but I have my code and raw data online. The code is a bit messy since I learned R to do this analysis, but the code is at https://sites.google.com/site/tpmscapstonecode/. I will add the paper to the page as soon as my partner and I finish.

Comment: I tried it again using your modified theme and it works for me. See my edit above.